# Unity GetComponent(string Script)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to get component from object by string variable. How can i do it?

Here is my current code:

```
Canvas.GetComponent<Global_Variables>().Active_Figure.GetComponent(Script_Name).Cancel();
```

But I get the following error in the console :

> Assets/Scripts/Cell.cs(62,20): error CS1061: Type UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for Cancel' and no extension method Cancel' of type UnityEngine.Component'

Comment: Not sure how often you are using `GetComponent(string)` but that's slow. Why are you doing that? What's wrong with the code in your question?

Comment: I can't call Cancel() bc i can't get script by GetComponent(Script_Name)

Comment: Do you get any error? What is Cancel()? I think you should post the script and how you are tying to access it.

Comment: Cancel() is a function. I'm trying to call it by Canvas.GetComponent().Active_Figure.GetComponent(Script_Name).Cancel(). But i can't do it bc of unity. It write me Assets/Scripts/Cell.cs(62,20): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for `Cancel' and no extension method `Cancel' of type `UnityEngine.Component' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the result returned by `GetComponent()`.

I will assume that the `Cancel` function is defined in a class (or interface) called `Cancelable` your script are inheriting from (or implementing).

```
Cancelable myScript = Canvas.GetComponent<Global_Variables>().Active_Figure.GetComponent(scriptName) as Cancelable;
myScript.Cancel();
```

EDIT :

Next time, don't forget to post your code correctly formatted, and to put any additional information which could help how to resolve your problem (such as the error the console gives you)

Comment: No. That's useless for me. I have an GameObject with this script on it. This script must be universal for all classes =/

Comment: Well, the Cancel is defined in which class ? Replace the declaration `Script_Name myScript` by `Name_of_the_class_implementing_Cancel myScript`

Comment: I need to change data type... example: Pawn Script = new Pawn() if i chose Pawn and if i chose King i need asign King Script = new King()

Comment: Answer my question : Where is declared the `Cancel` function ? Both in `King` and `Pawn` class or in a base class ? You should think about using Interfaces (`ICancelable` for example), and you will be able to do :

`ICancelable myScript = Canvas.GetComponent<Global_Variables>().Active_Figure.GetComponent(Script_Name) as ICancelable; myScript .Cancel();`

Comment: It works, but it's a bad code:
switch(Script)
{
case "Pawn":
Canvas.GetComponent<Global_Variables>().Active_Figure.GetComponent<Pawn>().Cancel();
break;
case "Rook":
Canvas.GetComponent<Global_Variables>().Active_Figure.GetComponent<Rook>().Cancel();
break;
}

Comment: Cancel is declared in all figures

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov You need an interface or parent superclass. Something that the Pawn, King, etc. classes all inherit from that you can cast to that has the `Cancel()` method defined.